# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/libs/settings/settingsType.ts' does not provide an export named 'SettingsInterface'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to import a TypeScript interface into a file, but I keep getting:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/libs/settings/settingsType.ts' does not provide an export named 'SettingsInterface' (at index.ts:1:9)

This is rather confusing as `settingsType.ts` *does* have an export named `SettingsInterface`.

```js
interface SettingsInterface {
    personalization?: {
        darkMode: boolean
    }
}

export {SettingsInterface}
```

The `import` statement in `index.ts` looks like this:

```js
import {SettingsInterface} from "./settingsType.js"
```

Both `index.ts` and `settingsType.ts` are in the same directory. Could this be an issue with my build tool (Vite) or what?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/731#issuecomment-678625456

Essentially, what I have to do is instead of `import` and `export`, it's `import type` and `export type`.

So `settingsType.ts` now looks like:

```js
interface SettingsInterface {
    personalization?: {
        darkMode: boolean
    }
}

export type {SettingsInterface}
```

And the `import` in `index.ts` is now:

```js
import type {SettingsInterface} from "./settingsType.js"
```